# Weka MLP multiple outputs

Tags: csv, weka, multiplayer, perceptron

I'm using the multiplayer perceptron on Weka to classify data. Classification output should be a unique binary vector associated with certain input, e.g., 1, 1, -1, 1, -1, -1, 1. Output vector is 31-element long while input is 39-element vector of real numbers.  That is, the output cannot be represented by one column in the CSV file. Rather, I should have 31 columns for output values (class) beside the 39 columns of the input. I know how to use Weka when I have  one-column classes, but with such vector output I have a problem. I must have it like that because I need to compare it with MLP ANN in Matlab that hase 31 outputs in the output layer. Therefore, I cannot assign an abstract symbol for each unique combination in order to have one coloumn in my CSV. Your help is highly appreciated. Thanks in advance and have a nice day

Comment: Binary vector would have values 0 and 1. Are you sure your output is binary  vector?